# Are TempData Keys Case Sensitive?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Not sure if this has been asked, I could not find it searching the title provided.  My question is:

**Are TempData keys in ASP.NET case sensitive?**

Example:

```
TempData["sampleKey"] = 5;
```

If I try to access it using:

```
TempData["SampleKey"]
```

will I get the value?

**EDIT:**

I understand this is easy to try (and I have now) the reason I posted this question was because I could not find a solution by searching.  Trying it will always be the best way to figure something out, but I thought I would ask the question anyway to have it out there for all to see.

Comment: you should try this !!!!

Comment: Wouldn't it have been faster to actually try it instead of posting the question?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting so many down votes.  I understand I could try this and it would be a quick thing to test, however this is a community where information is shared.  I searched for this, and could not find an answer, and yes I could have just tried it myself, but I saw an opportunity for helping others that may search the same thing.  If this is bad use of the website then I did not realize that.  A little explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not case sensitive. You can put in whatever case you want as the key, and it still comes up every time. Why they chose to do it this way, who knows...

**EDIT**
This is also true for `ViewData`.

Comment: This is correct, I tried it as well and case does not matter.  Thanks for the ViewData bit too.

Comment: No prob. Sorry if my comment wasn't worded well - "what have you tried?" is generally the first thing people here want to see before helping with a problem. As a software dev, you'll find that documentation is good, forums are better, but nothing beats getting your hands dirty and writing some code. It's the best way to learn or answer questions like this, especially when things you read aren't always correct.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I understand that getting your hands dirty is always going to be the best (and with something this easy the fastest as well), plus I always test answers and make sure they are correct anyway.  That being said, typically when I search something and I can't find the solution I feel its worth asking the question to get it out there.  That way if someone does not find it as easy to implement as others then they can at least search for the solution.